# Two-dimensional array in memory

Tags: c#, arrays, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Array memory allocation - paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900677/array-memory-allocation-paging)

Does `byte[,] myArray` is always in continuous memory block?

I have some code which works with images stored in such arrays, everything works fine, but I just ask for sure.

EDIT: I work with unsafe code.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7900793/706456). There is a [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7900786/706456) that: *"In C# you can't guarantee that the memory block will be contiguous. The CLR tries to allocate the memory in one contiguous block, but it may allocate it in several blocks..."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's always there, in memory and will be memorized consecutively.

take a look : [True Unsafe Code Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374815/true-unsafe-code-performance)

And msdn says you can use without think about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28k1s2k6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: and, "Use pointers like anyone do not use." The best solution ever to faster things up ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/597790/1109215