# Get position of address in array 2d

Tags: c#, c++, arrays

To get the position of an array in `c++` you can do the following:

```
class Slot
{
public:

    int Color;
    std::string name;
    /*.... more properties*/
};

int main()
{
    Slot pix[60];

    Slot& randomSlot = pix[12];
    randomSlot.Color = 12;
    randomSlot.name = "sdsd";

    Slot* addressOfSlot = &randomSlot;
    Slot* arrayStart = pix;

    //get the original pos
    int x = addressOfSlot - arrayStart;
}
```

1. how would you do it to get the x and y positions of a `2d array` like this? :

   ```
   Slot pix[60][21];
   ```

I want to use this approach because I'm gonna be working with pointers/references and I would like to have a fast approach to get the original position,

2. Also can you do this in c# with unsafe code or something similar?

Comment: how would you represent [30][30]?  Are you trying to get the 1d position of a 2d position?

Comment: Are you saying that given a value, you want to find its indicies in the array?

Comment: @NathanOliver the same way its represented in C# `byte[,] myArray`, Im sure is continuous memory in c#, Im looking to do this in c#  but c++ was the only way to explain the problem. [Two-dimensional array in memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575735/two-dimensional-array-in-memory)

Comment: @RonBeyer that's correct.

Comment: In C# at least, given that you want an O(1) lookup, a better data structure would be a hash table or dictionary. If the X/Y is important, you can store that along with the value as a Tuple.

Comment: to find index of array refer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909784/how-do-i-find-a-particular-value-in-an-array-and-return-its-index

Answer (score 1):

You can map from a 2D array of size `ROWS x COLS` to a 1D array of the same size and vice versa via

```
array2D[x][y] <-> array1D[x * COLS + y];
```

where `COLS` is the number of columns. This uses the fact that in C or C++ the arrays are stored in what's technically called [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). Fortran or MATLAB use column-major order, so the indexing is transposed.