# Hotspot JVM array allocation

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

I've been searching for days for proper documentation on Hotspot JVM, with regards to the way arrays are allocated (an). By this, I mean what's the actual structure of the array, when allocated in memory, is it made out of contiguous blocks or is it a tree like structure.

I need the structure to come up with a formula of the size (a formula which takes size of object and array length as inputs). From the tests I've run and from what code I could understand, I've come up with arrays being contiguous structures. Like an object, they have a header, an int for counter and then the blocks for data. My tests couldn't detect structure overhead that would be incurred by using a tree like structure, though I can easily envision such an event.

If anyone here is more informed, I'd greatly appreciate it! My best results searching have yielded this link:
[Array memory allocation - paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900677/array-memory-allocation-paging)
Thanks!

Comment: You might try downloading the source for OpenJDK.

Comment: Downloaded it already. But I find it barely readable. Seems like I would have to understand the whole allocation mechanism for all objects in order to get to the size function. But yes, that's what I'm currently/ have been doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably a bit late, but here it goes:

Arrays are allocated as contiguous blocks. The size can be derived by using the class [sun.misc.Unsafe](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/misc/Unsafe.java#Unsafe) (Some great tutorial [here](http://robaustin.wikidot.com/how-to-write-to-direct-memory-locations-in-java)), which gives you native access to raw memory. For example, the allocated size of an array of `int`s is (in bytes):

`Unsafe.ARRAY_INT_BASE_OFFSET + Unsafe.ARRAY_INT_INDEX_SCALE * length`

Due to implementation of the hotspot-jvm, all objects are aligned to 8 or 4 bytes (depending on your platform: AMD64 or x86_32), so the actual size of an array is increased to a multiple of 8 or 4 bytes.

Using the unsafe class we can inspect the actual data:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Get the unsafe object.
    Unsafe unsafe = null;
    try {
        Field field = sun.misc.Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        unsafe = (sun.misc.Unsafe) field.get(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
    //define our array
    int[] data = new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    //calculate length (ignoring alignment)
    int len = Unsafe.ARRAY_INT_BASE_OFFSET + Unsafe.ARRAY_INT_INDEX_SCALE * data.length;
    //Some output formatting
    System.out.print(" 0| ");
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        //unsafe.getByte retrieves the byte in the data struct with offset i
        //This is casted to a signed integer, so we mask it to get the actual value
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(unsafe.getByte(data, i)&0xFF);
        //force a length of 2
        hex = "00".substring(hex.length()) + hex;
        //Output formatting
        System.out.print(hex);
        System.out.print(" ");
        if(i%4 == 3 && i != len -1){
            System.out.println();
            if(i < 9){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print((i+1) +"| ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Which results in:

```
 0| 01 00 00 00 
 4| 00 00 00 00 
 8| 32 02 8c f5 
12| 08 00 00 00 
16| 00 00 00 00 
20| 01 00 00 00 
24| 02 00 00 00 
28| 03 00 00 00 
32| 04 00 00 00 
36| 05 00 00 00 
40| 06 00 00 00 
44| 07 00 00 00
```

So we can see, that the integers a saved in little-endian starting at offset 16. And the integer at offset 12-16 is the length of our array. The bytes at 0-12 make up some magic number, though I am not quite sure how that works.

***Note***

I would advice against writing code which uses properties of your JVM, as it is highly unportable and can probably break between updates. Nevertheless, I think you can safely assume that arrays are allocated as contiguous blocks.

Comment: God, I'm late as well. Yeah, that's what I was suspecting. Thanks a million, it answers my question.